# Passing property to Gradle Tooling API ProjectConnection

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-tooling-api

I am using gradle tooling api and I encountered the following scenario.
There is a project that applies a certain plugin **P** which creates a task **T** only if the property **shouldApplyP** is passed.

Hence, if you will run `./gradlew tasks --all` you won't see task **T**, but if you will run 
`./gradlew -PshouldApplyP tasks --all` you will see task **T**.

In gradle tooling api, once a `ProjectConnection` has created I can do 
`connection.getModel(GradleProject.class).getTasks()`

But I can't see this specific task. Is there a way to pass the project connection this property 
`-PshouldApplyP` so it will be presented in the `getTasks()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection.newBuild()
    .withArguments("-PshouldApplyP", "tasks --all")
    .run()
```